# IIS URL Rewrite For URL Link with %3D

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, url-rewriting

I am having an issue where someone has posted a URL for my asp.net mvc3 site that contains %3D instead of an equal sign after my id parameter like this: http://ultimategamedb.com/Article/Article?id%3D398210c1-529e-4909-9793-a11b8a832dcc .  I have tried various rewrite rules but cannot seem the URL to rewrite correctly to: http://ultimategamedb.com/Article/Article?id=398210c1-529e-4909-9793-a11b8a832dcc .  It is a problem because the URL with the %3D gives a 404 error.  If possible I would like to create a rule that rewrite any URL with % encoding to the correct decoded values.  If this is not possible I would just like to know how to rewrite my article URLs to ensure that a %3D will never show up for the equals sign in an Article URL again.

Could anyone explain to me how I would go about creating these rewrite rules?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options:

1. Write your own provider which will replace *%3D* with *=*.

   Reference: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module
2. In `Application_BeginRequest`, replace your path:

   ```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

       // Search for %3D and replace.
       path = path.Replace("%3D","=");

       HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(path);
   }
   ```