# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?) in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have seen similar question in SO, and i tried them but dont know why it didnt meet my requirement

i get this error in website, actually our site works this way, when a users click a product on our site, we redirect them to another site

and in sql db, column  site is stored this way : `http://another.com/`

so when user clicks the button in our site, this works fine, he is redirected another.com

but when i change  site column in sql db to `http://another.com/GiftPack/PackageDetail?packageid=41`

i get this error with following url in our site

`http://oursite.com/Product/90/httpcolonslashslashanotherdotscom/GiftPack/PackageDetail%3fpackageid%3d41`

**this what i tried thus far:**

from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2011/08/26/a-potentially-dangerous-request-value-was-detected-from-the-client.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

**in controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Product(int prodid, string site)
{
return Redirect(site.Replace("colon", ":").Replace("slashslash", "//").Replace("dots", ".")
.Replace("%3D", "=").Replace("%3F", "?").Replace("slash", "/"));
}
```

**in web.config**

```
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" 
 requestPathInvalidCharacters="*,:,&amp;,\,?,=" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
```

may i know what wrong i am doing, any help would be great.

Comment: i tried `[AllowHtml]` in my model property in class [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7306222/2218697), but still same error with `:`

Comment: i have updated my return redirect by using url re-write for `?,=,/` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530880/iis-url-rewrite-for-url-link-with-3d), does anyone have any idea  ?

Comment: I have never seen .NET html encode `http://` to `httpcolonslashslash`.  Where is this coming from?

Comment: @Tommy, i have just replaced `//`, you can check the `return Redirect` it works for 'http://another.com/' but for `http://another.com/GiftPack/PackageDetail?packageid=41` it gives the error, hope you read my question

Comment: I did read your question.  I still don't understand how this `http://another.com/GiftPack/PackageDetail?packageid=41` is turning into this `httpcolonslashslashanotherdotscom/GiftPack/PackageDetail%3fpackageid%3d41`.  Also, to answer your question, since you are sending the product id into your action method, just pull the DB record of the product and redirect to the product URL from that method.  No longer are you doing some weird translations on URLs.

Comment: @Tommy, i did that before , `return Redirect(site);` , but resulted in same error,  gonna give  try with `return new RedirectResult("yourURL", true); `

Comment: @Tommy, now it is working i used `Replace` method, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally this worked for me using [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

**in controller:**

```
public ActionResult Product(int prodid, string site)
{
return Redirect(site.Replace("colon", ":").Replace("slashslash", "//").Replace("dots", 
".").Replace("slash", "/").Replace("ques", "?").Replace("equal", "="));
}
```

**in view:**

```
<a target="_blank" class="btn btn-sm" href="@Url.Action("Product/" + pro.prodid
+ "/" + pro.site.Replace(".", "dots").Replace(":", "colon").Replace("//", "slashslash")
.Replace("=", "equal").Replace("?", "ques").Replace("/","slash"))">
Click to Go</a>
```

Note: pro is the element name inside my `foreach` loop

for more you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client),

hope this helps someone.